# Powerpoint 2010 viewer in a website

Tags: html, powerpoint

I want to view a PowerPoint presentation in a new window when a end user clicks a link to it,i don't want it to be downloaded,

Comment: You can export a PowerPoint presentation for web. The design is horrable. It it's possible its better to transform to a http://prezi.com/ presentation I think.

Comment: Its not helping @JackPoint

Comment: Could you explain why thats not helping.

Comment: I dont want to create a new presentation,the presentation its already created just need to upload it so that end users can view it on a new window